# Screen On and Off Without Locking

Tags: android, android-sensors

So I need to turn the screen off and on in conjunction with the proximity sensor.

Currently I use the following code.

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Window myWindow = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = myWindow.getAttributes();
        if (event.values[0] == 0) {
            // near
            winParams.screenBrightness = 0.0f;
        } else {
            // far
            winParams.screenBrightness = 1.0f;
        }
        myWindow.setAttributes(winParams);

    }
```

However, when the screen brightness is set to 0 the phone is locked and the application goes into background/pause mode. This is not what I want. All I want is the application to continue running in foreground just not be displayed to the user.

The reason I need to do this rather than use a background service is because I am porting an app over to Blackberry 10, and background services are not supported. Hence needing the application to stay in foreground.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not go for service then if need to run application on background only?

Comment: Good question, trying to port over to Blackberry and run in Android Runtime however background services aren't supported hence needing to keep in foreground.

Comment: some time back I used similar thing for J2me to keep light low or high but that wasn't for long and used threading ...